sorting content of headerName in AggridReact
unable to see and use icon of sort functionality in aggridreact next to headername,while using info icon which is next to headername to see tooltip content while hovering it
In the below code only for this headername sorting is missed in aggridreact since iam passing content to ToolTip component by headerComponent property and in Tooltip component iam displaying tooltip content while hovering info icon placed next to headerName in UI
{
headerName: "GreatTime",
field: 'sample',
flex: 2,
sortable:true,
cellRenderer: componentLink,
headerClass: '',
headerComponent: ToolTip,
headerComponentParams: {
content: (


Great Date and Time


Details of this grid


),
},
},
